# Relative path seperators for windows and linux in python

Tags: python, linux, windows, path, operating-system

I am creating a program and in this program, my folder structure is something like this

```
-> images
   -> image_1.png
-> test.py
```

In `test.py`, I need to access `image_1.png` via a relative path such as `images/image_1.png` in Linux. But in windows, it's `images\image_1.png`.

From my research, I have found out that `/` also works in windows as a path separator. Is this applicable to this case? Do I need to use `os.sep` or something like that, or in **all relative paths** `/` will work fine as a path separator in both windows and Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.path.normpath` as shown below. It can adjust to both Linux and Windows as per the system and it also resolves the path into the shortest possible path to the destination. Ex: `/home/foo/../A` will be resolved to `/home/A`.

Usage:

```
import os.path
 
# Path
path = './home//user/Documents'
 
 
# Normalize the specified path
# using os.path.normpath() method
norm_path = os.path.normpath(path)
 
# Print the normalized path 
print(norm_path)
# prints home/user/Documents in Linux
# prints home\user\Documents in Windows
```

For more info read this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-normpath-method/

Comment: Tested in Windows 11 and it works